# How to replace underscore with dashes when building XML document with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm building a new XML document using the following code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do
  reginfo {
    client_type_id client_type == :associate ? ASSOCIATE : CLIENT 
    parent_ {
      id_ client_type == :associate ? associate_id : customer_id
      client_type_id client_type == :associate ? ASSOCIATE : CLIENT  
      vsn client_type == :associate ? associate_vsn : customer_vsn
    }
  }
end
```

The tags above listed as `client_type_id` show up in the XML file like `client_type_id`, but that is not the correct XML tag name format. I need them to be `client-type-id`.

I tried replacing the line with:

```
:"client-type-id" client_type == :associate ? ASSOCIATE : CLIENT
```

but I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
    :"client-type-id" client_type == :associate ? ASSOCIATE : CLIENT 
                                 ^
```

or:

```
:"client-type-id" (client_type == :associate ? ASSOCIATE : CLIENT)
```

but I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '}'
        :"client-type-id" (client_type == :associate ? ASSOCIATE : CLIENT)
                           ^
```

Is there a way to tell Nokogiri::XML::Builder:

1. on a per-line basis, to use dashes for a tag name and does it have a different syntax?
2. that for the entire document, during creation or after, to use dashes for all underscores in element names so that it forms correctly formatted XML element names?

Comment: You can use a string method like `.gsub` to replace `_` with dashes `-`

Comment: You are also missing the local variable between the pipes after the `do`. example: `doc = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|`

Comment: @Cyzanfar `|xml|` is not a local variable, it is block variable and since OP did not use it, it might be easily omitted. Block vars are not mandatory.

Comment: True, it is a block variable however it is local to the context of the block therefore it is not wrong to call it a local variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fancy way of doing this:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  ...
  xml.send :"client-type-id", (client_type == :associate ? ASSOCIATE : CLIENT)
  ...
end
```

Comment: Interesting. That syntax still left it complaining about the == in the next argument but wrapping everything with the parentheses seemed to resolve that `xml.send(:"client-type-id", (client_type == :associate ? ASSOCIATE : CLIENT))`. However, now it is complaining about the other tags that were working before adding the block variable `xml` ... does mean I have to change the rest of the syntax for all of the tags that worked as expected to use the `xml` variable now?

Comment: I guess it does, I put `xml.` in front of all of the rest of the elements and now it is working as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer with parenthesis I missed.